# How do emus/ostriches/rheas have their upper leg connected to the rest of their body?

Tags: zoology, anatomy

I'm working on a model for educational graphics of an emu in conjunction with other information, but there aren't a lot of great reference images. The thing that's most unclear is how the upper leg around the femur is connected to the rest of the body because it's always obscured by feathers.

Mainly, is the leg connected to the rest of the area around the hip only half way through the femur, at the distal joint of the femur, or past the distal joint of the femur to the tibia? Elephants seem to have the third option, while horses seem to have the second option, and wolves seem to have the first option, so there are many possibilities without a clear generalization.
Below are the three options with the red indicating how far up the body the leg is connected to the skin of the hip area.

[image]

Comment: Try typing "emu skeleton" into your search engine: https://www.google.com/search?q=emu+skeleton&sa=G&complete=0&hl=en&gbv=2&prmd=ivns&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&ved=0ahUKEwjy74zWsffYAhUC2WMKHWP9CQAQsAQIFA

Comment: I wish it was that brain-dead simple, but it would benefit you to know that bones aren't muscles and dermis tissue, so a skeleton doesn't tell someone how the muscles and dermis extend to connect to the rest of the body from the leg tissue, it's a supporting structure.

Comment: Well, googling for "featherless ostrich" *does* retry some results...

Comment: Tried that too, some of the first results were: a jumping featherless chicken, an owl chimera, a 3-headed camel, a t-rex, and an ostrich laying an egg.

Comment: @John Joe: Sorry, I wasn't clear on what you were asking.  Searching for "emu musculature" finds this: https://peerj.com/articles/716/ and this: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/(SICI)1097-4687(199810)238:1%3C23::AID-JMOR2%3E3.0.CO;2-O/full (which is paywalled, but you might find an online copy).